# Zara's product image functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate Zara's product functionality: (click on product image)
https://www.zara.com/es/en/woman/outerwear/view-all/tweed-coat-with-metal-buttons-c733882p5205048.html

I have it almost working from a jsfiddle I found:
https://jsfiddle.net/y6p9pLpb/1/

```
$(function() {
  $('.product-wrapper a').click(function() {
    $('.image-zoom img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('.image-zoom').show();
    $('.product-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
    return false;
  });

  $('.image-zoom').mousemove(function(e) {
    var h = $(this).find('img').height();
    var vptHeight = $(document).height();
    var y = -((h - vptHeight) / vptHeight) * e.pageY;

    $('div img').css('top', y + "px");
  });

  $('.image-zoom').click(function() {
    $('.image-zoom').hide();
    $('.product-wrapper').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

There's only one thing I can't solve.

When I click on the image and expands, this one jumps to match its respective position relative to the cursor.

Is there any way I can solve that? Like Zara does...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you would like some sort of transition, rather than jumping straight to the large view?

Comment: Not exactly, my problem comes when the image is already expanded and I move the cursor for the first time. You will see that the image re-adjusts its position ("the jump") to match the position of the cursor.

Comment: Ah ok, there's just one section you need to remove to get it to work. I posted what to remove in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the image jumps to your cursor once you move it, right? This should do what you're looking for!

https://jsfiddle.net/8z67g96b/

I just broke out the position change as a function, and also call it when you click the thumbnail - that way, the image already has the cursor's position influencing it when it first appears.

```
function zoomTracking(event){
  var h = $('.image-zoom img').height();
  var vptHeight = $(document).height();
  var y = -((h - vptHeight) / vptHeight) * event.pageY;
  $('.image-zoom img').css('top', y + "px");
}

$('.product-wrapper a').click(function(e) {
 $('.image-zoom img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
 $('.image-zoom').show()
 zoomTracking(e);
 $('.product-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
 return false;
});

$('.image-zoom').mousemove(function(e) {
 zoomTracking(e);
});
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: One last question Will. it seems that when you can scroll (for example, having a second image so content is larger) the effect of the jump happens again. (1. Scroll to the bottom / 2. Click image / 3. Image jumps) Any idea why? jsfiddle.net/8z67g96b/1

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, it has a section relating to the position of the mouse and the width/height of the image:

```
  $('.image-zoom').mousemove(function(e) {
    var h = $(this).find('img').height();
    var vptHeight = $(document).height();
    var y = -((h - vptHeight) / vptHeight) * e.pageY;

    $('div img').css('top', y + "px");
  });
```

Simply remove this portion and it won't do any moving with the mouse, just expand onClick.